# Unable to port FSCTL_GET_RETRIEVAL_POINTERS call to C#

Tags: c#, c++, winapi, memory, interop

I'm running into an odd problem trying to call `DeviceIOControl` with FSCTL_GET_RETRIEVAL_POINTERS in C#. I've tried the code from [Jeffrey Walls blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jeffrey_wall/archive/2004/09/13/229137.aspx) as well as my own code but keep running into the same problem. The problem seems to be in the `Extents` structure in `RETRIEVAL_POINTERS_BUFFER`. When `Extents[0]->NextVcn` is `1` and `Extents[0]->Lcn` is `217550` in C++, in C#, I keep getting `Extents[0]->NextVcn` is `4294967296` and `Extents[0]->Lcn` is `934370135244800`. The same with `RETRIEVAL_POINTERS_BUFFER->StartingVcn`, when it should be `0`, in C# it becomes some other number (like `101` or `2016`).

### C# Code (Not Working)

```
        // Get cluster allocation information
        PInvoke.LARGE_INTEGER StartingVCN = new PInvoke.LARGE_INTEGER();
        PInvoke.RETRIEVAL_POINTERS_BUFFER Retrieval;
        IntPtr pDest = IntPtr.Zero;
        uint RetSize;
        uint Extents;
        uint BytesReturned = 0;

        // Grab info one extent at a time, until it's done grabbing all the extent data
        // Yeah, well it doesn't give us a way to ask L"how many extents?" that I know of ...
        // btw, the Extents variable tends to only reflect memory usage, so when we have
        // all the extents we look at the structure Win32 gives us for the REAL count!
        Extents = 10;
        RetSize = 0;

        const uint RETRIEVAL_POINTERS_BUFFER_SIZE = 28;

        StartingVCN.QuadPart = 0;

        GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(StartingVCN, GCHandleType.Pinned);
        IntPtr StartingVCNPtr = handle.AddrOfPinnedObject();

        do
        {
            Extents *= 2;
            RetSize = RETRIEVAL_POINTERS_BUFFER_SIZE + (uint)((Extents - 1) * Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(PInvoke.LARGE_INTEGER)) * 2);

            if (pDest != IntPtr.Zero)
                pDest = Marshal.ReAllocHGlobal(pDest, (IntPtr)RetSize);
            else
                pDest = Marshal.AllocHGlobal((int)RetSize);

            Result = PInvoke.DeviceIoControl
            (
                Handle,
                PInvoke.FSConstants.FSCTL_GET_RETRIEVAL_POINTERS,
                StartingVCNPtr,
                (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(PInvoke.LARGE_INTEGER)),
                pDest,
                RetSize,
                ref BytesReturned,
                IntPtr.Zero
            );

            if (!Result)
            {
                if (Marshal.GetLastWin32Error() != PInvoke.ERROR_MORE_DATA)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("Error #{0} occurred trying to get retrieval pointers for file '{1}", Marshal.GetLastWin32Error(), FullName);

                    Info.Clusters = 0;
                    Info.Attributes.AccessDenied = true;
                    Info.Attributes.Process = false;
                    Info.Fragments.Clear();
                    PInvoke.CloseHandle(Handle);
                    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pDest);

                    return false;
                }

                Extents++;
            }
        } while (!Result);

        Retrieval = new PInvoke.RETRIEVAL_POINTERS_BUFFER(pDest);

        // Readjust extents, as it only reflects how much memory was allocated and may not
        // be accurate
        Extents = (uint)Retrieval.ExtentCount;

        // Ok, we have the info. Now translate it. hrmrmr

        Info.Fragments.Clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < Extents; i++)
        {
            Extent Add;

            Add.StartLCN = (ulong)Retrieval.Extents[(int)i].Lcn.QuadPart;
            if (i != 0)
                Add.Length = (ulong)Retrieval.Extents[(int)i].NextVcn.QuadPart - (ulong)Retrieval.Extents[(int)i - 1].NextVcn.QuadPart;
            else
                Add.Length = (ulong)Retrieval.Extents[(int)i].NextVcn.QuadPart - (ulong)Retrieval.StartingVcn;

            Info.Fragments.Add(Add);
        }
```

#### P/Invoke Code

```
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    internal static extern bool DeviceIoControl(
        IntPtr hDevice,
        uint dwIoControlCode,
        IntPtr lpInBuffer,
        uint nInBufferSize,
        [Out] IntPtr lpOutBuffer,
        uint nOutBufferSize,
        ref uint lpBytesReturned,
        IntPtr lpOverlapped);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Size = 8)]
    internal struct LARGE_INTEGER
    {
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public UInt64 QuadPart;
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public UInt32 LowPart;
        [FieldOffset(4)]
        public Int32 HighPart;
    }
    internal struct Extent
    {
        public LARGE_INTEGER NextVcn;
        public LARGE_INTEGER Lcn;

        public Extent(IntPtr ptr)
        {
            IntPtr extentPtr = ptr;

            NextVcn = (LARGE_INTEGER)Marshal.PtrToStructure(extentPtr, typeof(LARGE_INTEGER));
            Lcn = (LARGE_INTEGER)Marshal.PtrToStructure(IntPtr.Add(extentPtr, 8), typeof(LARGE_INTEGER));
        }
    }

    internal struct RETRIEVAL_POINTERS_BUFFER
    {
        public int ExtentCount;
        public Int64 StartingVcn;
        public List<Extent> Extents;

        public RETRIEVAL_POINTERS_BUFFER(IntPtr ptr)
        {
            this.ExtentCount = (Int32)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr, typeof(Int32));

            ptr = IntPtr.Add(ptr, 4); 

            // StartingVcn
            this.StartingVcn = (Int64)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr, typeof(Int64));

            ptr = IntPtr.Add(ptr, 8); 

            this.Extents = new List<Extent>();

            for (int i = 0; i < this.ExtentCount; i++)
            {
                this.Extents.Add(new Extent(ptr));

                ptr = IntPtr.Add(ptr, 16);
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// constants lifted from winioctl.h from platform sdk
    /// </summary>
    internal class FSConstants
    {
        const uint FILE_DEVICE_DISK = 0x00000007;
        const uint IOCTL_DISK_BASE = FILE_DEVICE_DISK;
        const uint FILE_DEVICE_FILE_SYSTEM = 0x00000009;

        const uint METHOD_NEITHER = 3;
        const uint METHOD_BUFFERED = 0;

        const uint FILE_ANY_ACCESS = 0;
        const uint FILE_SPECIAL_ACCESS = FILE_ANY_ACCESS;

        public static uint FSCTL_GET_VOLUME_BITMAP = CTL_CODE(FILE_DEVICE_FILE_SYSTEM, 27, METHOD_NEITHER, FILE_ANY_ACCESS);
        public static uint FSCTL_GET_RETRIEVAL_POINTERS = CTL_CODE(FILE_DEVICE_FILE_SYSTEM, 28, METHOD_NEITHER, FILE_ANY_ACCESS);
        public static uint FSCTL_MOVE_FILE = CTL_CODE(FILE_DEVICE_FILE_SYSTEM, 29, METHOD_BUFFERED, FILE_SPECIAL_ACCESS);

        public static uint IOCTL_DISK_GET_DRIVE_GEOMETRY = CTL_CODE(IOCTL_DISK_BASE, 0x0000, METHOD_BUFFERED, FILE_ANY_ACCESS);

        static uint CTL_CODE(uint DeviceType, uint Function, uint Method, uint Access)
        {
            return ((DeviceType) << 16) | ((Access) << 14) | ((Function) << 2) | (Method);
        }
    }
```

### C++ to C# Code (Working)

#### C# Code

```
        uint Extents = 0;
        ulong StartingVcn = 0;
        IntPtr ExtentsPtr = IntPtr.Zero;

        bool ret = PInvoke.GetRetrievalPointers(Handle, ref Extents, ref StartingVcn, ref ExtentsPtr);

        IntPtr ptr = ExtentsPtr;

        Info.Fragments.Clear();

        for (uint i = 0; i < Extents; i++)
        {
            PInvoke.Extent Extent = new PInvoke.Extent(ptr);
            Extent Add;

            Add.StartLCN = Extent.Lcn.QuadPart;

            if (i != 0)
            {
                // Get previous extent
                PInvoke.Extent PrevExtent = new PInvoke.Extent(IntPtr.Subtract(ptr, 16));
                Add.Length = Extent.NextVcn.QuadPart - PrevExtent.NextVcn.QuadPart;
            }
            else
            {
                Add.Length = Extent.NextVcn.QuadPart - StartingVcn;
            }

            Info.Fragments.Add(Add);

            ptr = IntPtr.Add(ptr, 16);
        }
```

#### P/Invoke C# Code

```
    [DllImport("DLL.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    internal static extern bool GetRetrievalPointers(
        IntPtr hFile,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] ref uint ExtentCount,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U8)] ref ulong StartingVcn,
        ref IntPtr ExtentsPtr
        );
```

#### C++ Code

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
    EXTERNAPI bool GetRetrievalPointers(HANDLE hFile, DWORD &ExtentCount, UINT64 &StartingVcn, void **Extents) {
        // Get cluster allocation information
        STARTING_VCN_INPUT_BUFFER  StartingVCN;
        RETRIEVAL_POINTERS_BUFFER *Retrieval;
        unsigned __int64           RetSize;
        unsigned __int64           ExtentsCount;
        DWORD                      BytesReturned;
        BOOL                       Result;

        // Grab info one extent at a time, until it's done grabbing all the extent data
        // Yeah, well it doesn't give us a way to ask L"how many extents?" that I know of ...
        // btw, the Extents variable tends to only reflect memory usage, so when we have
        // all the extents we look at the structure Win32 gives us for the REAL count!
        ExtentsCount = 10;
        Retrieval = NULL;
        RetSize = 0;
        StartingVCN.StartingVcn.QuadPart = 0;

        do
        {
            ExtentsCount *= 2;
            RetSize = sizeof (RETRIEVAL_POINTERS_BUFFER)+((ExtentsCount - 1) * sizeof (LARGE_INTEGER)* 2);

            if (Retrieval != NULL)
                Retrieval = (RETRIEVAL_POINTERS_BUFFER *)realloc(Retrieval, RetSize);
            else
                Retrieval = (RETRIEVAL_POINTERS_BUFFER *)malloc(RetSize);

            Result = DeviceIoControl
                (
                hFile,
                FSCTL_GET_RETRIEVAL_POINTERS,
                &StartingVCN,
                sizeof (StartingVCN),
                Retrieval,
                RetSize,
                &BytesReturned,
                NULL
                );

            if (Result == FALSE)
            {
                DWORD dwLastError = GetLastError();
                if (dwLastError != ERROR_MORE_DATA)
                {
                    free(Retrieval);

                    return (false);
                }

                ExtentsCount++;
            }
        } while (Result == FALSE);

        // Readjust extents, as it only reflects how much memory was allocated and may not
        // be accurate
        ExtentsCount = Retrieval->ExtentCount;

        // Ok, we have the info. Now translate it. hrmrmr
        ExtentCount = ExtentsCount;
        StartingVcn = Retrieval->StartingVcn.QuadPart;
        *Extents = Retrieval->Extents;

        return true;
    }

#ifdef __cplusplus
};
#endif
```

### Other

The one thing I noticed is that when I convert `Extents[0]->NextVcn` and `Extents[0]->Lcn` to a `LARGE_INTEGER` (see code above) then the `HighPart` is switched with `LowPart`, like the following. However, switching HighPart with LowPart does not work `RETRIEVAL_POINTERS_BUFFER->StartingVcn` (because HighPart/LowPart is a number and they should both be `0`).

#### Wrong LARGE_INTEGER

```
LARGE_INTEGER.HighPart = 2;
LARGE_INTEGER.LowPart = 0;
```

#### Expected LARGE_INTEGER

```
LARGE_INTEGER.HighPart = 0;
LARGE_INTEGER.LowPart = 2;
```

I'm wondering if there's something that's changing the memory or if I'm not working with the memory properly? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Extents[0]->NextVcn is 4294967296 and Extents[0]->Lcn is 934370135244800

These are not random numbers.  Convert them hex and you'll see that they are the exact same values you got in your C++ code, just offset by 4 bytes.  In other words, you are reading misaligned data.  The bug is located here:

```
    ptr = IntPtr.Add(ptr, 4);
```

You hard-coded the offset to RETRIEVAL_POINTERS_BUFFER.StartingVcn to 4.  But that field requires alignment to 8 since it contains a 64-bit value.  So there's 4 bytes of extra padding between the fields.  Fix:

```
    ptr = IntPtr.Add(ptr, 8);
```

Okay both in 32-bit and 64-bit code.

Comment: Thank You!!! I've been trying to figure this out for hours now. I looked at the memory dump and noticed that extra 4 bytes but couldn't figure out why it was there.